# Browser is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I added in my karma-config.js this frameworks:['ng-scenario','jasmine'],
throw the error browser is not defined.My project is angular seed(https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project added extra login page

my command prompt run

karma start karma.conf.js

browser is not defined.

my karma.conf.js

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'ng-scenario'],

plugins: ['karma-ng-scenario', 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-chrome-launcher'],

files: [
  'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
  'app/lib/angular/angular-*.js',
  'test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/js/*.js',
  'test/unit/*.js'
],

exclude: [
  'app/lib/angular/angular-loader.js',
  'app/lib/angular/*.min.js',
  'app/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js'
],
```

Comment: Add `browsers: ['Chrome'],`

Comment: Off-topic: do you know that for AngularJS Karma is no longer recommended as e2e-testing framework? Now it's Protractor. And if you only do unit-testing, you can ommit 'ng-scenario'. Your config file seems to be a mix between unit- and e2e-test!?